# Secure way of using aws amplify with SPA

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

When using aws amplify with `SPA` (React, Vue, Angular...) is it a good practice to use `USER_SRP_AUTH`. It seems like a bad idea storing UserPoolId and ClientId on the client.

Am I getting this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Those params are safe to publish.
See [this aws forum question](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=757990#757990).